# Groovy ConcurrentHashMap forEach call

Tags: java, groovy, java-8

**groovy 2.4.7**

I'm trying to iterate ConcurrentHashMap in groovy, trying the call

> forEach(long parallelismThreshold, BiConsumer action)

```
def Map wrapperMap = processFileContents(fileContents) 
//processFileContents returns a ConcurrentHashMap
wrapperMap.forEach {1000, (key, value) -> 
...
}
```

It's throwing error like,
Groovy:unexpected token: 1000 @ line 60, column

How can I invoke forEach with parallelismThreshold value provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the 1000 in the wrong place. The only thing within the curly braces should be the closure.

You need to pass two arguments to forEach, the first being 1000 and the second being the closure to apply to each element.

```
map.forEach(1000, { (k, v) -> 
  println("$k -> $v")
})
```